# How to change this value in react native

Tags: react-native

i have `data` and i want, if i do any change in this input field the array will change or another way is create new state include updated data.
How to do it?

```
const data = [
  {a1 : 23},
  {a1 : 22},
  {a1 : 11},
  {a1 : 15},
]

{
  data.map((v)=>{
     <TextInput
        value ={v.a1},
        placeholder ="enter value"
     />
  })
}
```

current Output :
it create 4 time `inputfiled` and inside it  have `a1` values.

expected Output:
if i change any inputfiled the data will change means supposed i change 3th input filed and enter 50  and hite button my expected output is..

```
[
  {a1 : 23},
  {a1 : 22},
  {a1 : 50},
  {a1 : 15},
]
```

i hope are you getting my problem. thanks

Comment: you need to add change  `onChangeText={}` on input.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `index` parameter of the `map` function to determine which `TextInput` you are using. Then use the `onChangeText` to change the state.

```js
const [inputData, setInputData] = React.useState([
  {a1 : 23},
  {a1 : 22},
  {a1 : 11},
  {a1 : 15},
])

function handleOnChangeText(newText, index) {
    setInputData(prev => prev.map((item, idx) => idx === index ? newText : item))
}

return <View>
   {data.map((v, index)=>{
     <TextInput
        value ={v.a1}
        onChangeText={(newText) => handleOnChangeText(newText, index)}
        placeholder ="enter value"
     />
  })}
</View>
```